# TouchableOpacity:Why did not trigger onPress,But triggered onLongPress?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPressIn={() => { console.log(Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000)), 'onPressIn') }}
    onPressOut={() => { console.log(Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000)), 'onPressOut') }}
    onPress={() => { console.log(Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000)), 'onPress') }}
    onLongPress={() => { console.log(Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000)), 'onLongPress') }}>

    <Image
        source={{ uri: item.images.medium }}
        style={styles.item_image}
    />

</TouchableOpacity>
```

**console.log**

```
1574921523 "onPressIn"
1574921523 "onLongPress"
1574921523 "onPressOut"
```

Why did not trigger onPress,But triggered onLongPress?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onlongpress

[image: console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpSnc.png)

Comment: can you try by commenting onLongPress or onPressIn or onPressOut. May be control is passed to other callbacks.

Comment: But I don't know why this is happening? Isn't it reasonable?

Comment: why you need all callbacks ?
FYI : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15088

Comment: delayLongPress={1500}

Comment: hey @ebyteebyte where are you checking onpress & onlongpress ...in the emulator ???

Comment: @ebyteebyte, don not use debug, it will work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am also facing the same issue while development, as onLongpress and
>   onPress both not working smoothly, but when i have made a build then
>   it is working as expected.

```
So try to make the build of the app, and it will work fine
```

Hope this helps....Thanks :)